# Score not calculating correctly

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm using the code below to calculate the total score for my teams :

My tables are also listed bellow .

The problem is that the scores are being incorrectly calculated for every team except the first one . The image should explain the desired outcome based on the info in my database.

Query :

```
mysqli_query($connection, "UPDATE teams SET totalscore=overall_score+IFNULL((SELECT sum(overall_user_score) FROM users WHERE team_id=id),0)") or die(mysqli_error($connection));
```

Tables :

```
users(name, team_id, overall_user_score)
teams(id, name, team_score, totalscore)
```

Image:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you have overall_score and totalscore as two different columns, but anyways:

If you are summing the totalscore column based on the overall_user_score column from the users table, you don't need to keep adding overall_score (in the teams table) to the totalscore column. See [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c2da6/1/0) as an example.

Again, I'm not sure why you have both overall_score and totalscore as two different columns. If I'm misunderstanding the question, let me know.

Comment: Have you tried inserting new users with different team ids to see if the totalscore changes properly? Also, again, why do you have both overall_score and totalscore?

Comment: Okay , so it seems that its working out the score based on adding together the first two users from the image above

Comment: May have just fixed it . My bad

Answer (score 0):

Really stupidly left out the t. infront of the last id so query should be :

```
mysqli_query($connection, "UPDATE teams t SET totalscore=overall_score+IFNULL((SELECT sum(overall_user_score) FROM users WHERE team_id=t.id),0)") or die(mysqli_error($connection));
```